# Typed, nested map of map[string]interface{} returns "type interface {} does not support indexing"

Tags: go

I'm experiencing a very strange problem with typed nested maps.

```
gore version 0.2.6  :help for help
gore> type M map[string]interface{}
gore> m := M{"d": M{}}
main.M{"d":main.M{}}
gore> m["d"]["test"] = "will fail"
# command-line-arguments
/tmp/288178778/gore_session.go:13:8: invalid operation: m["d"]["test"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
/tmp/288178778/gore_session.go:14:17: invalid operation: m["d"]["test"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
error: exit status 2
exit status 2
gore> m["e"] = "this works"
"this works"
gore> m
main.M{"d":main.M{}, "e":"this works"}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does this suddenly fail just because the map is nested inside a map?

Comment: Because what you "get out" of a `map[T]interface{}` with indexing like `m["d"]` is _always_ of type `interface{}` and not a map and thus does not allow indexing (the `["test"]`). Dead obvious, or? And please do not rely on fmt.Println-style inspection as this does some magic. Remember that GO is statically typed. No magic. Just because you can store a map inside an empty interface does not mean that such a thing magically behaves like a map. It behaves like an empty interface.

Comment: @Volker I assume you also downvoted me. I'm somewhat new to Go, but I do understand the basics of the problem. What I don't understand is why it doesn't work after I've already specified that `m["d"]` will be of type `M`. How can I fix it? Is it even possible?

Comment: `m := M{"d": M{}}` this does not tell Go that `m["d"]` will always return a value of type `M`, the next line could overwrite `"d"` with another value of different type. You only specified that the values are of type `interface{}`, so every time you try to access a value of `m` it's type will be that which you specified, `interface{}`. From tha point on, you can use type assertion.

Comment: If you are "somewhat new to Go" I'd recommend the Tour of Go tour.golang.org. "I've already specified that m["d"] will be of type M" is plain wrong. m["d"] is of type interface{} because that is the value type of M. If you know that this interface contains a M you can type-assert it. See https://tour.golang.org/methods/15.

Comment: From the tests I've tried, you can't type assert inside a map. `M["d"].(M)` is not legal; type M is not an expression. I don't see any question that says how to assert the type of a map element, or if it's even possible, yet I've been downvoted twice...

Comment: @FredrickBrennan `m["d"].(M)` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @FredrickBrennan see an example of that here https://play.golang.org/p/M2m60-45ac

Comment: @mkopriva `m["d"].(M)["test"]` This is really cool :) Thanks! Please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take this :

```
foo:=map[string]interface{}{}
```

When you define a `map[string]interface{}`, you can set any type you want  (any type that fulfill the  [empty interface](https://tour.golang.org/methods/14) `interface{}` contract a.k.a any type) for a given string index.

```
foo["bar"]="baz"
foo["baz"]=1234
foo["foobar"]=&SomeType{}
```

But when you try to access some key, you don't get some int, string or any custom struct, you get an `interface{}`

```
var bar string = foo["bar"] // error
```

in order to treat `bar` as an string, you can make a [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) or a [type switch](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16).

Here we go for the type assertion ([live example](https://play.golang.org/p/OPUP9YPX3M)) :

```
if bar,ok := foo["bar"].(string); ok {
   fmt.Println(bar)
}
```

But as @Volker said, it is a good idea -as a beginner- to take the [tour of go](https://tour.golang.org) to get more familiar with such concepts.

Comment: In this case, where you're doing type assertion on the returned value, you can omit the *is-key-present* check since a non present key will return the zero value of the map value's type, in this case `(interface{})(nil)` and doing type assertion on that is fine, as long as you're using the comma-ok result from the type assertion https://play.golang.org/p/L3htM4xH8C.